# C# or C/C++ How to receive packets from client, filter & redirect them to server, receive from server & send to client

Tags: c#, c++, c, security

My question is said in one phrase, 'how can you redirect packets from a client to another process, receive packets from that process and send a response back to the original client'. If my question is not clear, an example of how this is used is in an anti-hack, network filtering for a game. The task I am attempting to accomplish is to build an application that will receive requests from a client, send it to another process (server) IF it passes a few rule checkings, receive the response from the server and send it back to the original client.

What I am looking for is someone who could outline the process of how I would do this in either C# or C/C++ (preferably C#) or to URL me to another question that is similar to mine with an answer.

Thank you a LOT in advance!

**EDIT 1**

Here is someone who is trying to do the same thing I am: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/871339-creating-packet-filter

Comment: What have you tried so far on your own..? any code examples you may want to share..?

Comment: Would the client and server be running on the same machine, in the same network, or spread out across the internet? Do you have control over either the client or the server? Is the question about doing this with any random packet type or are you targeting a specific protocol?

Comment: The target server is on the same machine. Packets are being sent through port 3000, so what I want is that the 'anti-hack' reads from 3000, if it passes some conditions then forwards it to the 'server' on port 3001 (or what ever I choose). If you get what I am trying to do?

I don't have any code examples, I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction with a code example.

Comment: @JacobPollack - Port 3000, TCP or UDP?

Comment: @Babcock I am using TCP protocal. Do you have an idea for how this would work?

Comment: @JacobPollack - This is the classic "Man-in-the-middle" scenario. Create a Windows service that listens on 3000 (`TcpListener`) and acts a client to your service listening on 3001. When you receive a message from a `TcpClient` generated by the `TcpListener`, perform your checks and then send out the message on your `TcpClient` connected to 3001. On response, you will need a way to identify which response is destined for which client (protocol specific) so when you receive a message from 3001 you can forward it on to the right client. Just a hint: Queueing will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

*redir* is a program that runs on Unix-ish systems that does TCP redirection.  GPL v2 license.  You'll have to code the anti-hack checking part yourself, but the main thing is that you'll be starting with something that already contains all the socket esoterica to do the port forwarding, code that would be quite a slog to write yourself if you've never dealt with any of it before.

[Source code](http://sammy.net/~sammy/hacks/redir-2.2.1.tar.gz)

Good luck.

Comment: Where in the question did he mention it would be running on *nix?

Comment: He didn't.  In fact, the desire for C# code suggests otherwise, but he didn't say, so I didn't assume.

Comment: Tip: C# in the tags generally means Windows unless the Mono tag is present.

Comment: I updated my thread with someone who is trying to do the same thing I am. Please take a look and then re-evaluate your reply.